# PHP fgets() is not working for php files

Tags: php, httprequest, fgets, fsockopen

I'm using Nginx 1.7.3 and PHP 7.0.

I created a test.php file like that

```
<?php

$header = '';
$header .= "GET /test2.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host:127.0.0.1\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close";

$data = $header . "\r\n\r\n";

if ($fp = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 80))
{
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    $res = '';

    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

echo $res;

?>
```

and I created a test2.php file like that

```
<?php

echo 1;

?>
```

then I executed the test.php file by accessing on 127.0.0.1/test.php, but It didn't working. It kept loading and didn't show any text.

so I tested like that

```
while (!feof($fp))
{
        echo 1;
        exit;
        $res .= fgets($fp, 1024);
}
```

I excuted it, and it printed '1'.
(I think fgets() doesn't work.)

but I excuted it for a text file as follows.

```
$header = '';
$header .= "GET **/text.txt** HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host:127.0.0.1\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close";
```

It works well. I don't know what I have to do. How can I use fsockopen() for PHP files on localhost. I googled about it much, but unfortunately It wasn't very helpful. If you know about that, please tell me how to do.

Comment: try fread($fp,256);

Comment: @CatalinB Thank you for your answer, but It isn't still working..